# How to sum daily resetting data using MySQL

Tags: mysql

I am attempting to plot data cumulatively from a MySQL table which logs a value, resetting to 0 every day. After selecting the values using `select * from table where DateTime BETWEEN DateA AND DateB`, the data looks like this: [current data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LCSPR.png). I would like the output to look like this: [preferred data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XsQTf.png), ignoring the daily resets.

As I am a novice in SQL I was unable to find a solution to this. I did, however, obtain the correct output in Matlab using a for loop:

```
output = data;
for k=1:(size(data, 1)-1)
    % check if next value is smaller than current
    if data(k+1)<data(k) 
        % add current value to all subsequent values
        output = output + (1:size(data, 1)>k)'.*input(k);
    end
end
```

I would like the final product to connect to a web page, so I am curious if it would be possible obtain a similar result using only SQL. While I have tried using `SUM()`, I have only been able to sum all values, but I need to add the last value each day to all subsequent values.

Comment: Please share more details, starting with a [mcve]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using CTE and comparing dates, you can sum all values each date.

Let's say that table1 below is defined.

```
create table table1 (col_date date, col_value int);
insert into table1 values
('2020-07-15',1000),
('2020-07-15',2000),
('2020-07-16',1000),
('2020-07-16',3000),
('2020-07-16',4000),
('2020-07-17',1000),
('2020-07-18',2000),
('2020-07-19',1000),
('2020-07-19',1000),
('2020-07-19',2000),
('2020-07-19',3000),
('2020-07-20',4000),
('2020-07-20',5000),
('2020-07-21',6000)
;
```

In this case, the query looks like this:

```
with cte1 as (
  select col_date, sum(col_value) as col_sum from table1
  where col_date between '2020-07-16' and '2020-07-20'
  group by col_date
)
select a.col_date, max(a.col_sum), sum(b.col_sum)
from cte1 a inner join cte1 b on a.col_date >= b.col_date
group by a.col_date;
```

The output is below:

```
col_date    |max(a.col_sum) |sum(b.col_sum)
2020-07-16  |8000           | 8000
2020-07-17  |1000           | 9000
2020-07-18  |2000           |11000
2020-07-19  |7000           |18000
2020-07-20  |9000           |27000
```

The column of max() is just for reference.